# wifi isn't working on kali linux (and downloads too)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, firefox, kali-linux

So I have kali linux on my VM (I use vm ware workstation pro 16) And whenever I try to download any update it tells me this :

```
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and when I try to go on firefox it gives me an error :

```
Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at www.google.com.

If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:`

    Try again later.
    Check your network connection.
    If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Kali 2022.3 as a VM on VMware Workstation Pro V16 and Internet and Updating works fine.

(1) Make sure your Kali Guest is set for NAT or Bridged and NOT for Host Only. It appears to be set for Host Only.

(2) Make sure when set for NAT that Kali is using VMware's hardware network connection. It will look like Ethernet.

Any VMware Guest uses the VMware hardware Network Connection, not the physical NIC.

If for some reason you wish to use a real network card, you need a USB NIC and then use VMware pass through and set up the card in Kali. You need a card that has Linux drivers.

Try making a new Guest machine to see if that works. Remember you must set Kali for VMware Hardware Network connection.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but it seems like I already Have it set to NAT And it still not working

Comment: There may be something wrong with the Guest machine. Any fix I can suggest requires Internet and update access  (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove)  ...  You may need to try a new Guest machine.  Remember you need to use VMware Hardware for the network connection not your host wireless.

Comment: do you mean redownload Kali linux ?

Comment: If you are using VMware Network hardware and it is not working, yes, download the Kali ISO and try a new machine. Use the Kali Bare Metal ISO from which to make a machien.

Comment: what do you mean by "VMware network hardware" how to check if I did ?

Comment: You need to look in the Kali Network settings . There should only be one. "Ethernet Wired Connection"

Comment: So I'm in the "Wired connection 1" settings, I see "general", "ethernet", "802.1x security" , "DCB", "proxy", "Ipv4 settings", "Ipv6 settings", where have I to go?

Comment: If those Kali Network settings are default (Mine are) and the Guest is set for NAT (mine is) then Internet should work. There may be something wrong with your Kali Machine because Standard Kali as a VMware guest works fine.

Comment: Then I have to install kali for the another time

Comment: thanks for your help :D

Comment: hey @John, I'm installing kali again, then a question came in my mind, If the vm ware is in the E:\ Disk, is it normal or Have I to put it in C:\ disk (C:\ disk contains windows)

Comment: VMware can open a Guest machine file on any local drive.